# Wiredep не работает для css в Gulp

Tags: gulp, bower

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с следующей проблемой, захотел вставить **Wiredep** в свою сборку **Gulp**, суть в том что я использую **gulp-file-include** и хотел что бы css библиотеки вставлялись в файл libs.css таким образом "@@include('path/to/libs')" а библиотеки js в файл  libs.js в каждом из файлов я прописал

```js
// bower:js
// endbower
```

и

```css
// bower:css
// endbower
```

в файл js все вставляется и работает без нареканий чего не могу скачать о файле css

**Файл js после выполнения таска**

```js
// bower:js
@@include('src/app/libs/get-style-property/get-style-property.js')
@@include('src/app/libs/get-size/get-size.js')
@@include('src/app/libs/eventEmitter/EventEmitter.js')
@@include('src/app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
@@include('src/app/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')
// endbower
```

**Файл css после выполнения таска**

```css
// bower:css
// endbower
```

**Таски с gulpfile.js**

```js
gulp.task('bower-css', function () {
    gulp.src('app/libs.scss')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: 'app/libs',
            fileTypes: {
                scss: {
                    replace: {
                        css:  '@@include("src/app/{{filePath}}")',
                        sass: '@@include("src/app/{{filePath}}")',
                        scss: '@@include("src/app/{{filePath}}")'
                    }
                }
            },
            ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
});
gulp.task('bower-js', function () {
    gulp.src('app/es6/libs.js')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: 'app/libs',
            fileTypes: {
                js: {
                    replace: {
                        js: '@@include("src/app/{{filePath}}")'
                    }
                }
            },
            ignorePath: /^(\.\.\/)+/
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/'));
});
```

**Так почему с JS все работает а с CSS нет?**

Comment: Может потому что вы не скомпилированные файлы sass и scss инклюдите.

Comment: та оно же css файлы должно инклудить